# Using ArcMap for Image Classification?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification

I am trying to classify an image with SVM and RF in ArcMap. I have trained the classifiers and have the classifier definition files. I tried to classify but could not get RF and SVM from the drop-down menu for classification.

Can someone guide me how to classify with SVM and RF in ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your `.ecd` (Esri Classifier Definition) file after training, there should not be any problem. Just run [Classify Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/classify-raster.htm) tool with your segmentation definitions (`.ecd` file) to get classified output.

If you are looking for an option for SVM in the `Image Classification` toolbar, however, the classification methods listed there serve to a slightly different purpose. The methods here are for [multivariate analysis/classification](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-multivariate-tools.htm). Please compare that with [segmentation based classification methods](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-segmentation-and-classification-tools.htm).